# Need SMTP authentication in my PHP form?

Tags: php, forms, email, smtp

i have created a form and it doesnt send out emails. I contacted my host and he said I need SMTP authentication. Form needs to send reservation info.

Here is my reservation.php file:

```html
<script>
/////////////////// RESERVATION FORM //////////////////////
        $("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function(){ 
            var str = $(this).serialize();
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;
            document.getElementById('submit').value='PLEASE WAIT';
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "apartments_reservation_send.php",
                data: str,
                success: function(msg){ 
                    $("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 
                        if(msg == 'OK') 
                        { 
                            result = '<div class="notification_ok">Thank you!<br />Your request is successfully sent!</div>';
                            $("#fields").hide();
                        }
                        else 
                        { 
                            document.getElementById('submit').disabled=false;
                            document.getElementById('submit').value='Send request';
                            result = msg;
                            autoReinitialise: true;
                        } 
                        $(this).html(result);
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
</script>

<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');"> 
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%" align="right" style="text-align: right;">
                                        Arrival Date<span class="REQ">*</span> &rarr; <input id="arrivalDate" name="arrivalDate" size="30" type="text" class="date-pick" /> 
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%" align="left" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <input id="departureDate" name="departureDate" size="30" type="text" class="date-pick" />
                                        &larr; <span class="REQ">*</span>Departure Date
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%" align="right" style="text-align: right;">
                                        Adults<span class="REQ">*</span> &rarr; 
                                        <select id="Adults" name="Adults"> 
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option value="0">0</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option> 
                                            <option value="2">2</option> 
                                            <option value="3">3</option> 
                                            <option value="4">4</option> 
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%" align="left" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <select id="Children" name="Children"> 
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option value="0">0</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option> 
                                            <option value="2">2</option> 
                                            <option value="3">3</option> 
                                            <option value="4">4</option> 
                                        </select>
                                        &larr; <span class="REQ">*</span>Children
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="25%" align="right" valign="middle" style="text-align: right;">Name<span class="REQ">*</span> :</td>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" size="86" /> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" valign="middle" style="text-align: right;">E-mail<span class="REQ">*</span> :</td>
                                    <td align="left" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="86" /> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" valign="middle" style="text-align: right;">Phone<span class="REQ">*</span> :</td>
                                    <td align="left" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" size="86" /> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">Message :</td>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top" style="text-align: left;">
                                        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="87"></textarea> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%" align="center" style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">
                                        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send request" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

and here is my reservarion_send.php:

```html
<?php 

$TO_EMAIL   = "info@thebunchofgrapesinn.com";
$FROM_EMAIL = "info@thebunchofgrapesinn.com";
$FROM_NAME  = "thebunchofgrapes.com";
$SUBJECT    = "The Bunch Og Grapes - Apartment Reservation";
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
    include 'functions.php';

    $ARIVAL_DATE        = trim($_POST['arrivalDate']); 
    $DEPARTURE_DATE     = trim($_POST['departureDate']); 
    $ADULTS             = trim($_POST['Adults']); 
    $CHILDREN           = trim($_POST['Children']); 
    $EMAIL              = trim($_POST['email']);
    $PHONE              = trim($_POST['phone']); 
    $NAME               = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $MESSAGE            = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $ERROR = '';
    if(!$ARIVAL_DATE) 
    {
        $ERROR .= 'Please enter Arrival Date<br />';
    }
    if(!$DEPARTURE_DATE) 
    {
        $ERROR .= 'Please enter Departure Date<br />';
    }
    //if(!$ADULTS) 
    //{
        //$ERROR .= 'Please pick number of Adults<br />';
    //}
    //if(!$CHILDREN) 
    //{
        //$ERROR .= 'Please pick number of Children<br />';
    //}
    if(!$NAME) 
    {
        $ERROR .= 'Please enter Your Name.<br />';
    }
    if(!$EMAIL) 
    {
        $ERROR .= 'Please enter Email address.<br />';
    }
    if($EMAIL && !ValidateEmail($EMAIL)) 
    {
        $ERROR .= 'Please enter valid Email address.<br />';
    }
    if(!$PHONE) 
    {
        $ERROR .= 'Please enter You Phone Number.<br />';
    }
    //if(!$MESSAGE || strlen($MESSAGE) < 15) {
        //$ERROR .= "Molimo unesite poruku. <br />Poruka mora imati najmanje 15 karaktera.<br />";
    //}
    
    $FULL_MESSAGE = "ARIVAL DATE = $ARIVAL_DATE\nDEPARTURE DATE = $DEPARTURE_DATE\nADULTS = $ADULTS\nCHILDREN = $CHILDREN\nNAME = $NAME\nEMAIL = $EMAIL\nPHONE = $PHONE\nMESSAGE = $MESSAGE";
    
    if(!$ERROR)
    {
        $mail = mail($TO_EMAIL, $SUBJECT, $FULL_MESSAGE,
             "From: ".$FROM_NAME." <".$FROM_EMAIL.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$FROM_EMAIL."\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail) {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$ERROR.'</div>';
    }

}
?>
```

and here is the link of the webpage http://thebunchofgrapesinn.com/apartments_reservation

I am not sure how to add SMTP authentication and what is wrong here, can someone help?

Comment: please have a look.  http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsmtp

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of php's [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function varies depending on the server OS. Windows doesn't have a built in non-SMTP option like Unix-based servers. `mail()` is also limited in general without some advanced knowledge of working with headers.

If it's not inappropriate here to recommend a tool for the job, [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is a convenient enough goto solution for sending email from php. If your server is Unix/Linux based, you can leave out `$mail->isSMTP()` and the related options and PHPMailer will use the server's sendmail implementation. If you are on Windows or have SMTP details handy, PHPMailer makes that simple enough.

Comment: I got phpmailer but I cant figure out how to connect it with my forms?

Comment: You wouldn't integrate it with your form in any special way. You'd use it in place of the `mail()` function and your special header handling inside your reservation_send.php script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), these are common libraries for sending smtp mails. PhpMailer is a little simpler than swift and documentations is easy to understand.

But you can write your own smtp client for this but first you need to learn how to make a socket connection in php. [PHPMailers smtp clas](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php)s is a good hint to create one.

If you have administrator rights for your server, you can connect your sendmail mail function to a smtp server, [here is a documantation how to](https://www.smtp2go.com/docs/sendmail/). Php has a [mail configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) option for smtp though i never used it before.

By the way, php.ini has a sendmail_path option to read your STDOUT data and send mail. If you want, you can change this sendmail_path param with a bash, php, or a python script. But i do not recommend it.

Comment: Yes I was trying to use Phpmailer but I dont understand how it works, and how to keep the form I have and connect it with phpmailer

Comment: First you need to clone phpmailer repository to your projects library or root folder. Then add **require __DIR__.'where_your_phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';** top of your reservation_send.php but make sure you enter the right path for it. After that you can take a look phpmailer's examples folder and use one you need like [https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps](this one).

Comment: and what should i put on the fields
$mail->Host = "mail.example.com";

$mail->Username = "yourname@example.com";

$mail->Password = "yourpassword";

Comment: You can get those from your provider or you can use another mail service provider like mandrill, gmail, yandex etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the host have SMTP already configured.
In order to debug test **mail()** function seperately.Just make a file like 'mail.php' and put the below code in to it :

```html
    <?php
         $email   ="PUT EMAIL ID OF USER HERE";      
    
        $subject ="Reservation Info";
    
        $headers = "From: " . '<thebunchofgrapesinn.com/>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    
     $message = "<html>
        <body>
          <p>Its Just A Testing Mail</p>
        </body>
        </html>";

    if(mail($email,$subject, $message, $headers)){
      echo 'mail sent';
    }

?>
```

Check weather it works or not.
Also prefer to use phpmailer.
[Here is the link for downloding PHPmailer class it also has example.](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)